# Does the release order of the Pathfinder series match the in-universe order?

Tags: chronological-order, pathfinder

The novels from the *Pathfinder* Roleplaying game campaign setting are all listed according to release date on the setting's [unofficial wiki site](http://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Category:Novels). Do the release dates coincide with the timeline sequentially?

Here is the list of published (and soon to be published) titles:

- Prince of Wolves
- Winter Witch
- Plague of Shadows
- The Worldwound Gambit
- Master of Devils
- Death's Heretic
- Song of the Serpent
- City of the Fallen Sky
- Nightglass
- Blood of the City
- Queen of Thorns
- Called to Darkness
- Liar's Blade
- Pirate's Honor

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this update was available on the [Pathfinder Wikia site](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Pathfinder_Wiki) when the question was written, but the same site [now has a page](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Pathfinder_Tales_suggested_reading_order) that gives a suggested reading order for the books.

It states that since characters rarely reappear, it is listed in author order, and does have "read before" and "read after" categories, however it does not appear to recommend that for any outside the individual author series. (i.e. read Author Y book X before Author Q book M)